How can I resolve the "Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)" error when booting Ubuntu
I'm trying to install ubuntu as a dual os system, but when booting i get the following error. https://imgur.com/a/zDCGBxM
I found a lot of people with a similiar problem where the answers are as follwing: EFI boot error: please append a correct device "root=" boot option
I have tried these solutions, but still get the same error.
(Please write if there is any needed information i have left out)

This question is similar to: Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
